# Understanding event loop with twisted and node

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to choose a platform to code my network application on, it will be a small realtime online game server. I am not very familiar with the async theory though I know how to write a little asynchronous code.

I both know javascript and python, on the same level.

So I was reading on twisted [here](http://krondo.com/blog/?p=1333) and he says:

> During a callback, the Twisted loop is effectively “blocked” on our
>   code. So we should make sure our callback code doesn’t waste any time.
>   In particular, we should avoid making blocking I/O calls in our
>   callbacks. Otherwise, we would be defeating the whole point of using
>   the reactor pattern in the first place. Twisted will not take any
>   special precautions to prevent our code from blocking, we just have to
>   make sure not to do it. As we will eventually see, for the common case
>   of network I/O we don’t have to worry about it as we let Twisted do
>   the asynchronous communication for us.

I wanted to see how this is different to how the event loop on `node.js` is done. I believe `node.js` implements the event loop and it never blocks, or am I missing something?

- I write somewhat blocking codes on my callbacks with `node.js` does this mean I'm making a mistake?
- Why is twisted called async and event driven when it still blocks?

Cheers,
Maj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twisted, node.js, and every other asynchronous framework behave the exact same way here: If you writing blocking code in your callbacks, the entire event loop is blocked until your callback is done.

Asynchronous frameworks are really great for doing I/O-bound work; the event loop never gets blocked waiting for I/O, because it can all be done in a non-blocking way. When there is data ready for reading, the event loop fires off your callback, the callback handles the data, and then the event loop takes control again. When you hear these frameworks being called "async" and "event-driven", it's referring to this non-blocking I/O + event loop model.

However, when you actually need to do some kind of processing with the data being sent/received, you need to be careful. Event loops are single-threaded; only one CPU-based operation can happen at a time. That means if you do some expensive calculation that takes 10 seconds in a callback, **your event loop is blocked for 10 seconds**. There's no extra magic in node.js that avoids this.

If you want to be able to do CPU-based operations without blocking your event loop, node.js (and twisted) have mechanisms for sending the CPU-bound work to a sub-process, and then fetching the results when the sub-process is complete. The [node.js About page](http://nodejs.org/about/) actually mentions this:

> But what about multiple-processor concurrency? Aren't threads
>   necessary to scale programs to multi-core computers? You can start new
>   processes via [child_process.fork()](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process.fork) these other processes will be
>   scheduled in parallel. For load balancing incoming connections across
>   multiple processes use the cluster module.

Comment: This is the best explanation I have seen so far. But I will try to keep the spot for the answer open for a few hours... I hope you don't mind. But this information is something I haven't found anywhere.

Comment: Also the suggestions you gave for my use case, (small scale realtime game server), is really nice. Thank you for that. Hope to see more suggestions on those too.

Comment: If I understand correctly. Use the event loop to only receive and send data, and use another process (child) to handle the parsing and the serializing of the data, and maybe another process (child) to handle the logic of the data received and what data to send.

Comment: Just to back up my point, [here's a blog post](http://zef.me/4561/node-js-and-the-case-of-the-blocked-event-loop) about a node.js server running into poor performance, because the event loop was being blocked by some json parsing that was taking longer than expected.

Comment: By `this information is something I haven't found anywhere`. I wasn't doubting you. I was thanking you for giving such information, something that I wasn't able to find anywhere else. :)

Comment: @majidarif You don't *always* need to do CPU-bound work in a separate process or thread, but if the CPU-bound work is going to take long enough to affect your ability to receive and respond to incoming requests in a way you deem unacceptable, then you should. You just need to be careful about this, because one of the main reasons to use a asynchronous framework is to avoid the headaches caused by threads/multiple processes. If you find you're using them for almost every request, you may as well just use a forking/threading based web server.

Comment: What kind of CPU bound task is considered long? data parsing and serialization can take a few micro-seconds. It's just a simple xoring of bytes. Then after xoring those messages, it is passed to a handler, then the handler does appropriate things like write/read to a database. Then serialize data, again just xoring, then send it to the client, So do you think this can be on only one thread?

Comment: @majidarif Data parsing can take a few milliseconds in some cases, but imagine a client just sent you 100MB of data to parse. Now its probably taking a few tenths of a second. Now imagine you're getting 10GBs of data. Now we're talking a few seconds. Now imagine there are 100 clients all sending you MBs or GBs of data, etc. All of a sudden parsing is taking up enough time to noticeably affect your ability to respond to clients. This may not be directly relevant to your use-case, but it's something to consider. (cont)

Comment: @majidarif One way to deal with this is to use subprocesses to deal with CPU-bound operations, but if you don't keep any shared state in-memory in your node.js server, you can also run multiple instances of the server behind a load balancer, which allows you to scale across CPU cores, too. Really, you should just make adjustments as you test your server and see how it performs. What you described (parsing some small amount of data and writing it to a DB), doesn't sound like it needs to be done in a separate process, assuming you're not dealing with thousands of simultaneous clients.

Comment: I do have to share the information of the clients connected, (sockets). I'm trying to write to support 1000 clients, simultaneously connected.

Comment: @majidarif I would suggest starting off simple, and have everything run in a single process. As you do scalability testing, find your bottlenecks and make the necessary adjustments (like moving CPU-bound work to a sub-process) to get performance where you want it. You don't want to spend too much time trying to optimize before you're sure it's actually required.

Comment: I was reading [this](http://zef.me/4561/node-js-and-the-case-of-the-blocked-event-loop) link you provided. He was showing code that he said was BAD. but never said how to fix it. Hmmm.

Comment: @majidarif He actually does hint at it: *"**You can limit the impact on your users by using a module like [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)**, but the message is clear: blocking the eventloop is bad, mkay?"* The same module is suggested at the very end of the quote in my original answer.